# Why does Vagrant occasionally 'forget' that there is already a VM running when I try to SSH into Vagrant machine?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, vagrant

I keep running into an issue where when I try to SSH into my vagrant environment, it gives me the following error to the console:

```
$ vagrant ssh
VM must be created before running this command. Run 'vagrant up' first.
```

I can verify that my vagrant VM is running by opening VirtualBox.

[image]

When I run `vagrant status` I get the following

```
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                note created (virtualbox)
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, especially since I can access the Jenkins install I have running on that machine.

If I actually tried running `vagrant up` it will attempt to create a new VM, and will fail because of port collissions.

I have come across other posts that suggested fixes involving deleting the VM and starting again when this happens, but that is not a feasible fix for me. I can't expect to do this, or have a team of developers constantly destroying their VMs.

Comment: Any solutions to this? I'm encountering the same issue described here.